# Android Navigation Architecture Component - Nav Drawer Icons

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-components

I'm currently using the Android Architecture Component's `Navigation`, but I'm running into an issue with my `Navigation Drawer`. It shows the hamburger menu when at my starting destination, but other `Fragments` are showing the up arrow. I believe I've setup my `navigation_graph` incorrectly.

Here you can see my nav drawer, showing 2 items, Home and Settings. When in either of these Fragments, you should see the Hamburger icon.

[image: nav drawer]

However, when navigating to the Settings Fragment, it shows the Up arrow.

[image: toolbar]

### navigation.graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

    <!-- Start at HomeFragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name=".HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/home">

        <!-- Navigate to the Search -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_search"
            app:destination="@id/nav_search" />
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:name=".SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings">

        <!-- Navigate to the Search -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_settings_to_nav_search"
            app:destination="@id/nav_search" />
    </fragment>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:name=".SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/search" />

</navigation>
```

I feel like `HomeFragment` and `SettingsFragment` should be related somehow but I'm not sure how to define that.

### main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/home" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### MainActivity

And then within `MainActivity`, I just set it up like this. I called `setupActionBarWithNavController`, but I also have to actually setup the nav drawer myself, and handle the `onNavigationItemSelected`.

```
private fun setupNavigation() {
    navController = findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawer_layout)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val current = navController.currentDestination.id
    if (item.itemId != current) {
        navController.navigate(item.itemId)
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawers()
    return true
}
```

build.gradle

```
// Navigation
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha04'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha04'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want Hamburger icon with Settings page also or some other icon? But not up button in Setting page.

Comment: Yes. Both would show the hamburger icon. As they're both items within the nav drawer. However, going to another screen, such as "Search" or "Details" would show an up icon.

Comment: Use two activities for Home and Settings page. Create a base activity and extend both the activities from it. In base activity call initialize navigation drawer and its functionalities. This should solve your issue.

Comment: I'm using the navigation library to reduce the number of Activities. I'm trying to following Google's suggestion of One Activity, Many Fragments.

Comment: Other solution can be use `FrameLayout` as container in common activity for both Home and Settings page. and replace the fragments programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177146/discussion-between-tauqir-and-advice-dog).

Answer (score 10):

In newer alphas (I have 1.0.0-alpha07) they added possibility to define `topLevelDestinationIds` when calling `AppBarConfiguration` constructor.

So I setup my NavController like this

```
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val config = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.fistTopFragment,
            R.id.secondTopFragment,
            ...
        ),
        dr.drawerLayout
    )
    tb.setupWithNavController(navController, config)
```

Where `dr` is MaterialDrawer and `tb` of course Toolbar.

Then it behaves more like Gmail, at least for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, the back stack is still preserved. Since I must handle item selection in MaterialDrawer by myself, I'm going to reduce back stack actions using global navigation actions with inclusive popTo to the root fragment of the navigation graph and use something like a "Welcome screen" for now.

Another way around could be custom handling of the `onBackPressed`. 
You must remove `app:defaultNavHost="true"` from your host fragment in activity layout first. Something like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    if (navController.currentDestination == null
        || navController.currentDestination!!.id in setOf(
            R.id.fistTopFragment,
            R.id.secondTopFragment,
            ...
        )
    ) {
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
        navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Sorry about the code, I'm still learning Kotlin, so there is probably much nicer way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid it is a [feature of navigation component](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupActionBarWithNavController(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)).

> The action bar will also display the Up button when you are on a non-root destination and the drawer icon when on the root destination, automatically animating between them.

If you want, you can try to use [setupWithNavController(NavigationView, NavController)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) and handle the toolbar yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the guidelines, and show a hamburger icon on "root destinations", and the up button on "non-root destinations", but it shows the up button on other "root destinations" other than the "home destination".

Comment: Well, according to creators it is intended behavior, so you are jus t fighting the library. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80555718

As for me, I actually like to have one starting screen even for drawer. When I go to settings, it is very likely, that when I press back, I want to go back to using the app and not end up in launcher.

Comment: Actually, one of the comments say it's actually a bug. And it's being tracked.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109675998

Comment: The issue you are referring to talks about nested graphs. That does not seem to be your case. But by all means give the new version a try.

Comment: I realized that I'm actually running `alpha04`, whereas the fix was in `alpha02`. I tried making my root destinations a nested graph, which makes a lot more sense, but it's still the same. And it's definitely not right, as going to a Fragment that SHOULD show the UP icon, pressing that doesn't work as expected, it opens the nav drawer instead of moving back.

Answer (score 2):

I made simple example for this issue. Solution is almost same as Almighty's answer. https://github.com/isaul32/android-sunflower

Create set of top level destinations at first

```
val topLevelDestinations = setOf(R.id.garden_fragment,
        R.id.plant_list_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
        .build()
```

and then override onSupportNavigateUp function like this

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Back arrow appearing on tab fragments associated with `BottomNavigationView` is an intended behaviour. However haven't seen it being used "as is" even in famous apps (Instagram, Youtube which have bottom tabs). If you navigate to different bottom tabs in Youtube app for example and click device back option, you'll notice it goes to previous tab fragment and not exit app. So bottomnavigationview tab fragments are not root destinations here.

Want to bring to notice additional important issues which you might encounter as you move forward:

- It does not allow for reuse of fragments in combination with `BottomNavigationView`
  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373186
- If you have multiple activities the up button does not navigate up to the previous activity
  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79993862

However there are several hooks you can use to customise the behaviour:

1. `onBackPressed` - to close drawer layout if open

   ```
   override fun onBackPressed() {
       if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
       } else {
         super.onBackPressed()
       }
    }
   ```
2. Add `navController.addOnNavigatedListener(..)` and inside the listener customise HomeAsUpIndicator icon
3. Override `onOptionsItemSelected` to customise menu with id `android.R.id.home` action
4. Set custom fragment navigator to customise how your fragments are treated (replace or show/ hide)

   ```
   navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
           .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return
   val customNavigator = CustomFragmentNavigator(navHostFragment.requireContext(),
           navHostFragment.childFragmentManager, navHostFragment.id)
   navHostFragment.navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(customNavigator)

   val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
   val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.main_nav_graph)
   navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
   ```

Remember navigation arch component is still in alpha, so use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use [NavController.OnNavigatedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnNavigatedListener) and use below code to set title.

```
@Override
public void onNavigated(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination) {
    mActivityBinding.toolbar.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
}
```

Remember to set label in your navigation graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think your menu items should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/home" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

</menu>
```

Hope this helps

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the sentiment here but it is a part of the library

> setupActionBarWithNavController
>
> Sets up the ActionBar returned by AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar() for use with a NavController.
>
> By calling this method, the title in the action bar will automatically be updated when the destination changes (assuming there is a valid label).
>
> **The start destination of your navigation graph is considered the only top level destination. On the start destination of your navigation graph, the ActionBar will show the drawer icon if the given DrawerLayout is non null. On all other destinations, the ActionBar will show the Up button. Call navigateUp(NavController, DrawerLayout) to handle the Up button.**

this to me is broken and not the desired result, so what i'm doing is still using it with the navigation view using

```
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController);
```

and then having a listener to update the title and anything else i want changed like this

```
   navController.addOnNavigatedListener((controller, destination) -> {
        setToolbarColour(R.color.primary);
        switch (destination.getId()){
            case R.id.dashBoard :
                setToolbarColour(android.R.color.transparent);
                break;
            case R.id.requests :
                toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.request));
                break;

        }
    });
```

I'm then creating a new navigation graph for each of these fragments, not great but i get my intended result